# Decoding nested JSON with Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decode

JSON =

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"results": [
               {
                  "geometry": {},
                   "name": "Cruise Bar, Restaurant & Events",
                   "vicinity": "Circular Quay W, Sydney"
                },
                {}
],
"status": "OK"
}
```

How do I retrieve name if it is nested within results?

Comment: what decoding logic have you tried?

Comment: Simply var name: String,
           var rating: Int

Comment: No, more than that. Show some code. The parsing, the decoding. And... where did `rating` come from?

Comment: SO is not "write code for me" service. Show what have you already tried, and what problems you've faced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam Try this i write sample code in playground using your Json. **root.results** will give you array of dictionary, you can easily traverse and get your desired name from it.

```
import UIKit

struct Root: Codable {
    let results: [Results]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case results = "results"
   }

}

struct Results: Codable {
   let name: String?
   let vicinity: String?
}

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)


do {
      let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data as! Data)

      if let name = root.results?.first?.name {
          print(name)
      }    

} catch let error as NSError {

    print(error.description)
}
```

Here is the json i have used.

```
{
"results": [{
            "name": "Cruise Bar, Restaurant & Events",
            "vicinity": "Circular Quay W, Sydney"
            }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shauket , where would I place the URL

Comment: url is of your json path, in your case your are getting data from server side just omit this step let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)

Comment: I did not down vote, in fact I upvoted. Your answer worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

**Model:**

```
 import Foundation
struct HtmlInitial: Codable {
    let results: [Result]?
    let status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case results, status
    }
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let name, vicinity: String?
}

extension HtmlInitial {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(HtmlInitial.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

**use model Like that :**

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "APIResponse", withExtension: "json")!

if  let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url) ,
    let initial = try? HtmlInitial.init(data: data),
    let result = initial.results?[0] {
    print(result.name)
}
```